# G-equivariant bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose $X$ is a smooth projective variety over $k$ and $G$ a finite group acting on $X$ with $\mathrm{char}(k)$ does not divide the order of $G$. Let $\mathcal{E}$ be a $G$-equivariant vector bundle. Then one has a $G$ action on $\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{E})$. Now consider $\mathcal{F}$ a $G$-equivariant vector bundle on $X$. Is $\pi^*\mathcal{F}$ a $G$-equivariant sheaf on $\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{E})$? (Here $\pi:\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{E})\rightarrow X$)

Comment: Duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/661357/g-equivariant-bundle