# G-equivariant bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This question is crossposted from mathstackexchange.
Suppose $X$ is a smooth projective variety over $k$ and $G$ a finite group acting on $X$ with $\mathrm{char}(k)$ does not divide the order of $G$. Let $\mathcal{E}$ be a $G$-equivariant vector bundle. Then one has a $G$ action on $\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{E})$. Now consider $\mathcal{F}$ a $G$-equivariant vector bundle on $X$. Is $\pi^*\mathcal{F}$ a $G$-equivariant sheaf on $\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{E})$? (Here $\pi:\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{E})\rightarrow X$)

Answer (score 0):

"$G$-equivariant" is not a property of a sheaf, it is an extra structure. So you have to define an action of $G$ on $\pi ^*\mathcal{F}$ compatible with the action on $\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{E})$. There is an obvious one: $\pi ^*\mathcal{F}$ is the fibre product $\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{E})\times _X\mathcal{F}$,   $G$ acts on both factors, you take the product action.